# Output array info in label C# give Cannot convert char to string

Tags: c#, arrays

as the title says I try to get an info from an array in foreach. 
This is for Microsoft form application!
What I try so far is :

```
       private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] names = new string[] { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };

            foreach (string element in names)
            {
                label3.Text = (string)element[1];
            }

        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what the underlying problem is? Even with the "fixes" I and a few others have suggested, you're still going to replace the text of that label with the last text in the array. What do you *want* the text of that label to be after the code has executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element[1]` is a char, as `element` is one of the strings from your `names` array.

So the error message is correct, you cannot cast a `char` to a `string`.

Perhaps you meant this:

```
label3.Text = element;
```

Comment: Tried with that, the problem is that I don't get any output at all. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The app was not execute the code properly

Answer (score 1):

`(string)element[1]` gets the second character in `string element` and then converts that to a `string`. (It's equivalent to `element.Substring(1, 1)`.)

What you probably want to do is just use `element`: `label3.Text = element;`

However, there is still an issue here, which is that `label3.Text` will end up being the *last* element of `names`. I doubt that this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change is:

```
private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] names = new string[] { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };

        foreach (string element in names)
        {
            label3.Text = element;
        }

    }
```

This will update the label to show Matt, then Joanne, then Robert.

If you would like to do it that way, you can use a `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    label3.Text = names[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
label3.Text = (string)element[1];
```

means display the first character of each element of your string array `names`. Get the first character, cast it to string and assign it to label text. Explicit casting from `char` to `string` is not allowed and that is why  you get error.

> Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'

You can fix that by using:

```
 label3.Text = element;
```

But this will lead to another issue, You will get end up with the last value in your array in the Label.

If you want to show all the values in an array separated by some delimiter like comma then use :

```
private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] names = new string[] { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };
    label3.Text = string.Join(",", names);
}
```